# Division by zero with arrays

Tags: php, html, arrays

Alright, I have an array from a server query on a game server that holds information. I made a progress bar that shows the current amount of players. The percentage of this progress bar is calculated like this

```
<span style="width: ' . $data['gq_numplayers'] / $data['gq_maxplayers'] * 100 . '%;"></span>
```

Now, if the server is offline I get problems as the array is empty and the division will be 0/0 and causes error. How do I bypass/solve this?

Comment: You should just be able to check `if($data){ echo... }`...

Comment: Always use `isset($var);` or array_key_exists (where $var = $data['gq_numplayers'] in this case) if you feel that a variable is potentially not going to be set. These are GOOD coding standards to follow. Ignore any answer that does not include a check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the use of an `if` statement would be the solution.

i.e.

```
if ($data['gq_maxplayers'] == 0) {
   echo '<span style="width: 0%;"></span>';
} else {
   echo '<span style="width: ' . $data['gq_numplayers'] / $data['gq_maxplayers'] * 100 . '%;"></span>';
}
```

Comment: @Ed Heal I used your solution and I'm very happy with the result.

Comment: Always use isset($var); or array_key_exists (where $var = $data['gq_numplayers'] in this case) if you feel that a variable is potentially not going to be set. These are GOOD coding standards to follow. Ignore any answer that does not include a check

Comment: @Mwayi - It is not good coding standards to do things that are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an if to check if data is not empty. You could use `array_key_exists('gq_numplayers', $data)` to check if there was or not a problem on the server.

If there is a problem you could show whatever message you want. Below is a code sample:

```
if (array_key_exists('gq_numplayers', $data)) {
    <span style="width: ' . $data['gq_numplayers'] / $data['gq_maxplayers'] * 100 . '%;"></span>
}
else {
    // Do whatever you want.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of munging the values, check to see if the denominator is `0` before you perform the calculation. If it is `0`, display the percentage as `0%`. If having a denominator of `0` is an unexpected condition, then you probably want to display an error message or say that the data are not available. For example:

```
$percentage = 0;
if ($data['gq_maxplayers'] > 0) {
   $percentage = ($data['gq_numplayers'] / $data['gq_maxplayers']) * 100;
}

echo '<span style="width: ' . $percentage . '%;"></span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an conditional to calculate the percentage. You can use an inline `if`

```
<span 
 style="width: ' . $data['gq_numplayers'] / 
                   (($data['gq_maxplayers'] != 0) 
                     ? $data['gq_maxplayers'] 
                     : 1) * 100 . '%;"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if the `$data['gq_maxplayers']` is 0 then calculate the width of your element.

```
<?php $data['gq_maxplayers'] = ($data['gq_maxplayers'] == 0) ? 0 : $data['gq_maxplayers']; ?>
<span style="width: ' . $data['gq_numplayers'] / $data['gq_maxplayers'] * 100 . '%;"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($data['gq_maxplayers']>0 ) { ?>
    <span style="width: ' . $data['gq_numplayers'] / $data['gq_maxplayers'] * 100 . '%;"></span>
<?php } else{ ?>
    <span style="width:0%;"></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You only need to check the denominator

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it the **inline shorthand way**...

```
echo '<span style="width: ' . ($data['gq_maxplayers'] != 0 ? $data['gq_numplayers'] / $data['gq_maxplayers'] * 100 : '0') . '%;"></span>';
```